# R - Subset string from nth position to first dot

Tags: r, string, subset

I have a list of filenames like this:

datalist

```
EU_AU_abc100.dat
EU_AU_abc200.dat
EU_AU_abc300.dat
EU_AU_abc.dat
```

I want to have this:

```
abc100
abc200
abc300
abc
```

How can I do that? I know the `substr(datalist, start = 6, stop = 12)` for example, but that doesnt suit for the last example. Any idea how to solve this? Can I use the .dat as stop-marker somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gsub`

```
gsub('.*_([^_]+)\\.dat','\\1',c("datalist EU_AU_abc100.dat","EU_AU_abc.dat"))
[1] "abc100" "abc"
```

`.*_` any character followed by a `_`
`([^_]+)` capture any character except a `_` between `.*_` and `.dat` as group 1. Then returns this group `\\1`